# My next badge is one that doesn't exist on meta (Informed)

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, badge-tracking

One of the features of the new user profile is the next badge section. As can be seen below, my next badge on meta is the Informed badge.

[image]

But meta does not have an Informed badge; see [the list of badges on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges). When I click on the box, a pop-up appears with the option to "Go get it". When I follow the prompt, I am taken to the main site tour.

> Can the Informed badge be removed from the possible next badges on meta (given that it doesn't exist)?

I am aware that I can change which badge is displayed under the next badge title, but that isn't really fixing the problem.

Comment: Related post on meta.SE in "New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list" thread: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253486#253486

Comment: Other "unobtainable recommended next badges" from the master list: [moderators cannot get Deputy/Marshal badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253468), [Excavator impossible on a new site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253497).